# UNO Cross-Platform Maps Control (WinUI + Android + iOS + Wasm)

Tags: maps, cross-platform, webassembly, uno, winui

I'm new to cross-platform UNO development.

I was looking for any Maps control that can work on multiple platform from a shared UI project. Has anyone come across one that works across WinUI + Android + iOS + Wasm? Is that even possible to have a common control like that to work across WinUI, Mobile and Wasm?

Any assistance is much appreciated.